# Mobile Image Revealed When Fowarded Using Outlook

Tags: outlook, html-email

I have an HTML email that has a creates a mobile version by using *{display:none!important;}* and has a media query that reveals it using *{display:block!important;}*.

When forwarded in Outlook, the email breaks and displays both images leaving a huge gap on the right side next to the mobile image.

Has anyone found a coding solution that would maintain the appearance when forwarded?

HTML

```
    <table width="570" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="deviceWidth">
    <tr>
        <td class="vanish">
            <table width="570" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="deviceWidth">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" style="color: #999; text-decoration: none;">
                            <img src="Desktop.jpg" width="205" height="171" alt="" class="deviceWidth" style="display: block; background-color: #343434;" border="0"></a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End One Column -->
<!-- Houdini Start -->
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="deviceWidth">
    <tr>
        <td style="display: none; visibility: none; width: 0px; height: 0px;" class="houdini">
            <a href="#" style="color: #999; text-decoration: none;">
                <img style="display: none; visibility: hidden; width: 0px; height: 0px; border: 0px;" src="Mobile.jpg" alt="" class="houdini" /></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- Houdini End -->
```

Comment: It seems my code was snipped off. The mobile HTML image code is:

              <!-- Houdini Start -->
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="deviceWidth">
<tr><td style="display:none; visibility:none; width:0px; height:0px;" class="houdini">
              <a href="#" style="color:#999; text-decoration:none;"><img style="display:none; visibility:hidden; width:0px; height:0px; border:0px;" src="Mobile.jpg" alt="" class="houdini" /></a>
              </td></tr>
              </table>
              <!-- Houdini End -->

Comment: This is the problem with forwarding emails. Since what you forward is the final, processed by outlook (or other) version of your mail, all the code that was not used in displaying it will not be forwarded. Outlook, gmail, yahoo and friends do change your code to display it, using proprietary classes, ids, etc..  I have not found a way to work around that, sadly.